# Calendar or user timezone with Office 365 API

Tags: azure, office365, outlook-restapi

Is it possible to get timezone of a user or its calendar through Office 365 or Graph API?

I know that you can get start and end timezone from specific event. But that does not help me.

Answer (score 2):

Sorry, we don't support this yet through Office 365 or Graph REST APIs.  This is on our roadmap to add, but I don't have a timeline to share.

Comment: Any updates on this feature?  It's critical to overcome a bug in all-day events where they are returned from midnight to midnight in UTC.

Answer (score 0):

The Microsoft Graph REST API now returns a `timeZone` field from [Get user mailbox settings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-get-mailboxsetting).

You can also retrieve just the timezone:

`GET /users/{id|userPrincipalName}/mailboxSettings/timeZone`

Unfortunately the format of timezone can vary - some details are in the docs.