# How to get user's Office 365 default timezone fom Micosoft Graph Api?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, office365api

Because some Graph API needs user's timezone, I want to get it.

Ex. [Find meeting times api](https://graph.microsoft.io/en-us/docs/api-reference/beta/api/user_findmeetingtimes) needs timezone settings.

Would you tell me how to get user's timezone settings from Office 365?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Calendar or user timezone with Office 365 API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29790029/calendar-or-user-timezone-with-office-365-api)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I found answer and share it to developers who have same questions.

To get user's Office 365 Timezone, you can get with [Get user mailbox settings API](https://graph.microsoft.io/en-us/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/user_get_mailboxsettings).

Please set "Read and write to your mailbox settings" permission in Azure AD.

Comment: I can only see that the timezone arrives as a string. Is the format of that string documented anywhere?

Comment: @yuvalm2 [This document](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms912391(v=winembedded.11).aspx) may be nice for you.

Comment: Link in the answer is broken. (Thanks Microsoft...)

Comment: Found it, new link is this one:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/office-365-api/api/version-2.0/mail-rest-operations#response-type-15

Answer (score 3):

The Microsoft Graph [now supports](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-get-mailboxsettings?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) requesting the TimeZone directly using either `GET /me/mailboxSettings/timeZone` or `GET /users/{id|userPrincipalName}/mailboxSettings/timeZone`